# Prolog replace element in a list with another list

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

*Hi, i am trying to replace an element from a list with another list and im stuck when turbo prolog gives me syntax error at the case where if C=A-> put in result list(L1) the list that replace the element.

```
domains
    list=integer*
    element=i(integer);l(list)
    lista=element*
predicates
    repl(list,integer,list,lista)
clauses
    repl([],A,B,[]):-!.
    repl([C|L],A,B,**[l(|L1])**:- C=A,repl(L,A,B,L1),!.
    repl([C|L],A,B,[i(C)|L1]):- repl(L,A,B,L1),!.
```

Thanks for help, problem solved (using dasblinkenlight code)

Comment: at the 3rd repl i'm trying to put in the list L1(who's type is element), at the head of it , all list B(who is the replacement of the element).

Comment: It's a plain syntax error, as the suggested by the fact a "syntax error" is reported.
Hint: [l(|L1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
concat([],L,L).
concat([H|T],L,[H|Res]) :- concat(T,L,Res).

repl([],_,_,[]).
repl([Val|T],Val,Repl,Res) :- repl(T,Val,Repl,Temp), concat(Repl,Temp,Res).
repl([H|T],Val,Repl,[H|Res]) :- repl(T,Val,Repl,Res).
```

I do not know if it is going to work in Turbo Prolog, but it works fine in SWI, and it does not use any built-in predicates.

`concat/3` pair of rules concatenates lists in positions 1 and 2 into a resultant list in position 3.

- The first `repl` deals with the empty list coming in; it is identical to yours, except it replaces singleton variables with underscores (a highly recommended practice)
- The second rule deals with the situation where the value `Val` being replaced is at the head of the list; it replaces the values in the tail, and concatenates the replacement list `Repl` with the result of the replacement `Res`.
- The last rule deals with the situation when the head value does not match the `Val`. It recurses down one level, and prepends the head of the initial list to the head of the result of the replacement.

As a side note, the cut operator `!` is rarely necessary. In case of this problem, you can definitely do without it.

Comment: Your a gentleman.Thank you very much for your help, works perfect.